# Is there a way in pytest to get a list of parameterized test node ids from within a fixture?

Tags: python, pytest

I'm trying to write a workaround for the inability of pytest/xdist to run some tests in serial, rather than all tests in parallel.

In order to do what I'm trying to do, I need to get a list of all the collected parameterized tests (so they look something like `path/to/test_module_name.py::TestClassName::test_method_name[parameterization info]`). I'm attempting to do so in a session scoped fixture, but can't figure out where this info is stored. Is there a way to do this?

I noticed at one point, when calling pytest with `--cache-show`, that 'cache/nodeids' was being populated with the exact node id information I need, but I can't seem to figure out when that does/doesn't happen, as it isn't consistent.

Answer (score 0):

While I couldn't find exactly what I was looking for, the problem with serializing tests while using the xdist plugin can be resolved with the following two fixtures:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def lock():
    lock_file = pathlib.Path('serial.lock')
    yield filelock.FileLock(lock_file=str(lock_file))
    with contextlib.suppress(OSError):
        os.remove(path=lock_file)


@pytest.fixture()  # Add this fixture to each test that needs to be serialized
def serial(lock):
    with lock.acquire(poll_intervall=0.1):
        yield
```